# Is Sitecore Item Web API v1.2 still available in Sitecore 9?

Tags: item-web-api

Have a 3rd party connector trying to use the Web API 1.2 to insert media items in to Sitecore. We are on Sitecore 9 and all the URLs are throwing a 404. The URLs start with "/-/item/v1/".

It looks like it was actively developed until 7.1 but was replaced by Item Web API v2. There seems to be a page for downloading the module but it doesn't work: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/SdnArchive/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi12.html.

Has it been deprecated and deleted?

Comment: I think you can use Sitecore Service Client in Sitecore 9. Read through this - https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-services-client.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Item Web API is not available, you can see available downloads here:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads.aspx

Upon further research, according to the official Sitecore documentation, Item Web API 1.2 is supported by Sitecore version 6.6 to 7.1 while Services.Client is supported by Sitecore version 7.5 and later.

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/SdnArchive/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi12/Installation.html

[image]